# toggling between two states - the elegant way

Tags: c#, logic

Simple example of toggling between two states:

```
if (this.lblColorChange.BackColor == Color.Red)
{
    this.lblColorChange.BackColor = Color.Blue;
} 
else
{
    this.lblColorChange.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

It works fine but are there alternative ways of coding this toggle? Possibly shorter, more elegant logic.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only one statement in if-else clause then we can remove curly braces.
So your code will be like

```
if (this.lblColorChange.BackColor == Color.Red)
    this.lblColorChange.BackColor = Color.Blue;
else
    this.lblColorChange.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

**OR**

we can use Ternary Operator

```
this.lblColorChange.BackColor = 
          this.lblColorChange.BackColor == Color.Red ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
```

We can also remove `this` from our statements if they do not cause any conflict.

```
lblColorChange.BackColor = 
                lblColorChange.BackColor == Color.Red ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
```

Comment: @whytheq: IMHO this is the most clean way of writing your code.

Comment: which is cleaner? - your way or the long way? I can see it is shorter (and prettier) but why is it "cleaner"

Comment: @whytheq: Edited my answer. Please look at it.